# Optimise SOQL in APEX Class

Tags: apex, soql

In the APEX class, I am checking conditions as below -

I am getting Oppty.Id as input parameter

Condition 1:

```
List<CUSTOM_OBJ> inprogressCheck = Select Id from CUSTOM_OBJ where OpportunityID = Oppty.Id and Status = 'In Progress';
```

If size() >0,  display error 1

Condition 2:

```
List<CUSTOM_OBJ> openCheck= Select Id from CUSTOM_OBJ where OpportunityID = Oppty.Id and Status = 'Open' and checkBoxField = 'Yes';
```

If size() > 0,  display error 2

How can I optimize it to avoid 2 SOQL queries. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you thinking of combining 2 logics then you have first find minimum criteria between them. In your case minimum criteria is *OpportunityID = Oppty.Id*. Then for remaining criteria you can use if else in for loop.

A simple way to can write query is

```
List<CUSTOM_OBJ> customObjList = Select Id, checkBoxField, Status  from CUSTOM_OBJ where OpportunityID = Oppty.Id;

List<CUSTOM_OBJ> inprogressCheck = new List<CUSTOM_OBJ>();
List<CUSTOM_OBJ> openCheckList = new List<CUSTOM_OBJ>();

for(CUSTOM_OBJ obj : customObjList){
     if(obj.Status == 'In Progress'){
         inprogressCheck.add(obj);
     } else if(obj.Status == 'Open' && obj.checkBoxField == 'Yes'){
         openCheckList.add(obj);
     }
}
```

if inprogressCheck.size() > 0 display error 1

if openCheckList.size() > 0 display error 2

But thing that we need to keep in mind while combining two queries is whether the data that we will get in combined query is not large then 50000 records.
we might have condition where there are 15000 record in open state and related to given opportunity,another 15000 record is in progress state and another 25000 record in queued state.

So if we do queries as you have done in that case code will work. But we try to combine our logic that will not work. Because whole records return in query will be 55000 records.(50000 is governor limit)

A better approach will be

```
List<CUSTOM_OBJ> customObjList = Select Id, checkBoxField, Status  from CUSTOM_OBJ where OpportunityID = Oppty.Id and (Status == 'In Progress' or (Status = 'Open' and obj.checkBoxField = 'Yes'))
 
 List<CUSTOM_OBJ> inprogressCheck = new List<CUSTOM_OBJ>();
 List<CUSTOM_OBJ> openCheckList = new List<CUSTOM_OBJ>();

 for(CUSTOM_OBJ obj : customObjList){
     if(obj.Status == 'In Progress'){
         inprogressCheck.add(obj);
     } else if(obj.Status == 'Open' && obj.checkBoxField == 'Yes'){
         openCheckList.add(obj);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Manjot.

Comment: @user105281 you can mark this as correct answer if this solve your issue